# Get date from meteor hash id

Tags: javascript, date, meteor, hash

I heard that hash ids in Meteor are generated basing on actual date (mixed with MAC address and something else). Is it possible to get data from existing Meteor `_id`?

Comment: That is not true. You may be referring to MongoDB `ObjectId`s, but those are not the default Meteor id generators.

Comment: @MasterAM is correct - taken from [the api docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-ObjectID): "ObjectID values created by Meteor will not have meaningful answers to their getTimestamp method, since Meteor currently constructs them fully randomly."